# Validating javax.persistance annotations?

Tags: java, hibernate, unit-testing, validation, mocking

I would like to programmatically check if an object fulfills what is specified by its javax.persistance annotations. I am creating a [fake](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TestDouble.html) for a Hibernate DAO for unit testing purposes. However, there was a defect that was not caught by the unit tests since the fake did not check the length of the field in the @Column annotation, which Hibernate did.

Obviously, I could add code to check those fields manually, but I'd rather use a method that would check all of them and thus would be up-to-date should the value change. I tried using `javax.validation.Validator` with [Apache Bean Validation](http://incubator.apache.org/bval/cwiki/index.html) but the Validator found no problems. Is there a function that would test without invoking a full blown Hibernate session?

To be clear, I am interested in simulating Hibernate's "type checking" and not bean validation itself, that was just something I was attempting to use to perform the check.

```
import javax.validation.Validation;
@Test( expected = IllegalArgumentException.class )
public shouldComplainBecauseOfNullsOrLength(){
    AclPermission acl = new AclPermission();
    acl.setTarget( "I   am    way    tooo     long   for     this   field   .    " );

    if(  !  Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator().validate( acl ).isEmpty()  )
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    fail( "Should have had a problem with null values." );
}
```

Currently using this code which I'd rather replace with something more robust.

```
        for(  String fieldName :   new String[]{ "target", "action", "recipient" }  ){
            final Field field = AclPermission.class.getDeclaredField( fieldName );
            field.setAccessible( true );

            final Column fieldConstraints  = field.getAnnotation( Column.class );

            final String fieldValue = (String) field.get( acl );
            if( ! fieldConstraints.nullable() && fieldValue == null  )
                throw new NullPointerException( fieldName + " is null." );
            else if( fieldValue != null && fieldValue.length() > fieldConstraints.length() )
                throw new IllegalArgumentException( fieldName + " is too long " + fieldValue.length() + "/" + fieldConstraints.length() );

        }
```

This is the class I am trying to validate:

```
public class AclPermission{
    @Id
    @Column(name="ID", nullable=false)
    @GeneratedValue(generator="system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name="system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
    private String id;

    @Column(name="TARGET", nullable=false, length=6)
    private String target;

    @Column(name="ACTION", nullable=false, length=10)
    private String action;

    @Column(name="RECIPIENT", nullable=false, length=6)
    private String recipient;

    //... getters and setters go here
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The attributes `nullable` and `length` on the `@Column` annotation are for schema generation.  They're used to tell the persistence provider how to set up the database.  They have nothing to do with runtime validation.  If you want to use a JSR-303 validator, you need to use JSR-303 annotations.

```
@Column(name="TARGET", nullable=false, length=6)
@javax.validation.constraints.NotNull
@javax.validation.constraints.Size(max=6)
private String target;
```

etc.

Comment: I'm not looking to use JSR-303 validator, I was looking to validate against the annotations that are already there. Also, this does not guarantee they will remain in sync' and will again in the future have something that works in unit test and fails in deployment.

Comment: I don't know of any framework that will use the schema definition as bean validation information.  They're usually regarded as separate concerns.

Comment: I'm not trying to use this for production just for adding a bit more reality to my unit tests since these are things that the database WILL check and throw an error for. I guess I'll hack something more robust in my own time.

Comment: Maybe you could migrate to using an in memory database for unit testing instead of mocking?  Or look into using bean validation at runtime anyway.  Depending on the app type and frameworks in use, it can be a much more versatile choice.

Comment: Bean validation would require additional work for which I wouldn't get credit and be probably be told to remove. Also, it doesn't guarantee that it an the Hibernate annotations are in sync.